# Convert jQuery option value to a non-object

Tags: php, jquery, variables, object

I am trying to pass the var text of an option to a load event in jquery but the code is not returning the text of the option value, I believe it is returning a object instead.  How do I get the string value of an option select.  here is the code so far

```
var statevar = $("#stateselect option:selected").val();



$( "#stateselect").change(function() {
console.log($( "#stateselect option:selected").val());
$( "#FactoryPricing" ).load("/include/StateSelection.php"+"?stateSELECT="+statevar);
});

});
```

The php variable stateSELECT= is returning blank when trying to call that variable.

Comment: Please don't change questions to indicate when they are solved, adding the green tick to an answer will mark it as such.

Comment: gotcha, do need to adjust the spelling error in the title if that is alright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log( $("#stateselect option:selected").text() );
```

**Example**

```
<option value="3" selected="selected">Three</option>

$("...... option:selected").text(); // returns "Three"

$(this).val(); // returns "3"
```

**UPDATE**

You may be looking for this:

```
$( "#FactoryPricing" ).load("/include/StateSelection.php"+"?stateSELECT="+this.value);
```

As in:

```
$(function() {
    var statevar = ""; 


    $( "#stateselect").change(function() {
        statevar = this.value;
        $( "#FactoryPricing" ).load("/include/StateSelection.php"+"?stateSELECT="+statevar);
    });

});
```

Comment: console.log return the variable fine.  It is when I try to use the variable anywhere else it shows blank.  For example if i do var="AL"  statevar would work but if I use the jquery $("#stateselect option:selected").val(); it returns blank.  but in console.log it does show the option selected for the state very awkward

Comment: When doing it this way it return stateSELECT=Select  

so for example

    <select id="state">
     <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
     <option value="AK">Alaska</option>

    </select>

I need to return the value of value="AL" instead of the Text within

Comment: Perfect! Thank you that is exactly what I needed, do you mind explaining why that worked?  As that is mind boggling

Comment: Simply because you fetched statevar BEFORE ever an option was selected and submitted this "empty" value to your PHP-Script. If you wanted statevar to contain the current  value, you should have assigned it in the "change" handler.

Comment: ahhhhhh dumb mistake makes sense!  You are awesome, Don't have a enough rep right now to upvode but I placed as an answer.  Will come back once i build up a rep under this name, usually I sign in at home but I am at work right now.  thanks!